# opencv python AttributeError

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I have installed Opencv 3.4.2 in anaconpa on Spyder Python 3.7, all running on Windows10 64bits.

My code:

```
import  cv2
import  numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread ("imageA.png",0)
plt.hist (img.ravel(), 256, [0,265])
plt.show()

cv2.waitkey (0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows ()
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\xcontrol\Anaconda3\envs\opencv2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 617, in _get_globals
    return ipython_shell.users_ns

AttributeError: 'ZMQInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'users_ns'
```

This error occurs in all of my codes

Comment: `cv2.waitKey()` should have a capital `K`, although I don't know if that's your issue.

Comment: This error seems more related to spyder than opencv.

Comment: I also think, but what causes this bug?